# AWS Lambda Container Image with Datadog error. datadog-lambda-js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dockerfile, datadog

community, I need your advice!

**Short explanation:** 
I'm trying to configure Datadog integration with AWS Lambda Container Image for NodeJS app.

I got an error from Lambda:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/function/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.handler'
```

Any ideas on how to debug this?

---

**Extended explanation:** 
I deployed Lambda Container Image. I created a Dockerfile like in the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-image.html#nodejs-image-clients) using a non-AWS base image.
My Dockerfile:

```html
# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM node:18-buster as build-image

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    make \
    cmake \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric

# Grab a fresh slim copy of the image to reduce the final size
FROM node:18-buster-slim

# Required for Node runtimes which use npm@8.6.0+ because
# by default npm writes logs under /home/.npm and Lambda fs is read-only
ENV NPM_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/.npm

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Set runtime interface client as default command for the container runtime
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/npx", "aws-lambda-ric"]


# Pass the name of the function handler as an argument to the runtime
CMD ["index.handler"]
```

Everything worked well, I tested the app and it worked.
Now I want to configure integration with **Datadog**. So I used [Datadog documentation for Lambda Container Images](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/aws_lambda/installation/nodejs/?tab=containerimage) and changed the Dockerfile with the installation of Datadog Lambda Library and Datadog Lambda Extension:

```html
# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM node:18-buster as build-image

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    make \
    cmake \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric

# Install the Datadog Lambda Library
RUN npm install datadog-lambda-js dd-trace

# Grab a fresh slim copy of the image to reduce the final size
FROM node:18-buster-slim

# Required for Node runtimes which use npm@8.6.0+ because
# by default npm writes logs under /home/.npm and Lambda fs is read-only
ENV NPM_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/.npm

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the Datadog Lambda Extension
COPY --from=public.ecr.aws/datadog/lambda-extension:55 /opt/extensions/ /opt/extensions

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENV DD_SITE="datadoghq.com"
ENV DD_API_KEY="SECRET"
ENV DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER="handler.handler"
# Redirect the handler function
CMD ["node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.handler"]
```

After that I got an error from Lambda:
Error: Cannot find module '/function/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.handler'

But the module presented. I ran the container locally and saw this directory.
[image: Proof that module presented]

What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the AWS base image and it works! 
A new Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20 as builder

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN npm install
RUN npm install datadog-lambda-js dd-trace

COPY --from=public.ecr.aws/datadog/lambda-extension:55 /opt/extensions/ /opt/extensions

ENV DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER="handler.handler"

CMD ["node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.handler"]
```